# Modelling a composite Time Series ID

Tags: azure-timeseries-insights

I have deployed the [Azure Industrial IoT Platform](https://github.com/Azure/Industrial-IoT) to my Azure subscription.  When it provisions Time Series Insights it uses a composite key for the Time Series Id.

I am having a hard time determining the format of the "Time Series ID" when modelling the instance.

**TSI Instance Configuration Error:**

[image]

**Error description:**

```
> Unable to create instance(s): Error in 1/1 instances.   >Instance-1:
> Values in a single time series ID
> '["i=2256,uat0b626473b51aad434992c48deefc9bb8d03ae7f2,uat0b626473b51aad434992c48deefc9bb8d03ae7f2"]'
> must match the time series ID properties
> '[publisherId:String,dataSetWriterId:String,nodeId:String]' defined
> for the environment.
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/time-series-insights/concepts-model-overview#time-series-model-instances) doesn't really show how it should be formatted.  (For example, should it include commas, square brackets, etc.)

The Time Series Id is showing as `(Empty)` when I view it in the UI, so I don't get any hints there:

[image]

Here is the sample telemetry:

```
  {
    "NodeId": "http://microsoft.com/Opc/OpcPlc/#s=AlternatingBoolean",
    "EndpointUrl": "opc.tcp://10.1.8.5:51200/",
    "ApplicationUri": "urn:OpcPlc:410bf7b98fc2",
    "DisplayName": "AlternatingBoolean",
    "Timestamp": "2020-08-12T19:07:38.4355693Z",
    "Status": "Good",
    "Value": {
      "Value": false,
      "SourceTimestamp": "2020-08-12T19:07:38.1007812Z",
      "ServerTimestamp": "2020-08-12T19:07:38.1007828Z"
    },
    "SequenceNumber": 1319,
    "ExtensionFields": {
      "EndpointId": "uat0b626473b51aad434992c48deefc9bb8d03ae7f2",
      "PublisherId": "uat0b626473b51aad434992c48deefc9bb8d03ae7f2",
      "DataSetWriterId": "uat0b626473b51aad434992c48deefc9bb8d03ae7f2"
    }
```

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your question.
You have encountered a bug in our experience that we are working on fixing.
Once fixed, we will update the documentation. Sorry about the inconvenience it caused.
Meanwhile you can add an instance with a composite ID through API, by following the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/dataaccessgen2/timeseriesinstances/executebatch#instancesbatchput

It should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Shipra.  Can you provide a little more context on the format of the composite ID?  Do I include field names, commas and/or square brackets or are the 3 fields essentially concatenated together?  Also wondering, the NodeID contains special characters ("/").  Are these allowed in a Time Series ID?